# Question about the equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Second equation of motion says that,
$s= ut+\frac{at^2}{2}$

From the first equation and third equation, I have derived a formula. That is,
$$v^2-u^2=2as,$$

$$v=u+at\Rightarrow v-u=at,$$
If we square this right equation, we get,
$$
v^2-u^2=a^2t^2.
$$

If the equations are same then,
$$a^2t^2=2as\implies at^2=2s.$$

If whatever I just wrote is correct why do we use the second equation?
Have I made a mistake? Because this formula allow us to find distance without any velocities and this formula will work in all scenarios.

I am still a kid though. Can this be a fourth equation of motion?

Comment: Well done for:
1) Questioning these results, and playing with them on your own
2) Having the intuition that something wasn't entirely right with your result
3) Coming to get the final say from here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns an algebraic error, not a concept of physics.

Comment: It is an algebraic error but, the alebric error is of equation of motion and equation of motion are of physics. So, the question stays valid. And I have realised my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This appears be to related to the [*freshman's dream*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) error:
$$
\left(x+y\right)^n= x^n+y^n
$$

is often the *hope* of students, but it is simply not true. Use $x=1$, $y=7$ and $n=2$ to see that it's false (64 one way & 50 the other).

You need to use the [distributivity property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) to expand the left side of your squared equation as,
$$
\left(u-v\right)^2=\left(u-v\right)\cdot\left(u-v\right)=v^2+u^2-2uv$$
which doesn't line up quite so well with your other equation, most notably because of the $+u^2$ term instead of the $-u^2$ you wrote.

Note, though, that your result is the $u=0$ case of the Second EOM:
$$
s=\frac{at^2}{2}\Longleftrightarrow 2s=at^2
$$
because in this case $\left(v+0\right)^2\equiv v^2$ and the "freshman's dream" does hold.

Comment: I should note that in abstract algebra, the freshman's dream can be true for certain [commutative rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring) (cf. this [math blog](https://www.anothermathblog.com/?p=72) or [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126275/) or [this other Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238531/) for examples)

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is incorrect. When you take $(V-U)^2=(at)^2$, what you get is $V^2+U^2-2UV=a^2t^2$, instead of $V^2-U^2=a^2t^2$.